# Verificar una celda vacía en un dataGridview c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvagregarp.Rows)
            {
                bool nulo = false;
                if(row.Cells["cantidad"].Value == null)
                {
                    nulo = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    nulo = false;
                }
}
```

El problema es que al verificar el código con un "MessageBox" para ver si realmente está validando celdas vacías me doy cuenta que a pesar que las celdas no tienen valores no los toma como null. De igual intenté colocar un "string.isNullOrEmpty" para posteriormente validar la casilla me tira un error de "Referencia a objeto no especificado" porque tengo que ponerlo como "string.isNullOrEmpty(row.Cells["cantidad"].Value.ToString())"

La duda es que antes me funcionaba pero parece ser que ahora no verifica que el value de la celda está vacío, pareciera que lo toma como si hubiese algo ahí.

Comment: De que tipo es el dato de la celda, string, int, objeto, etc?

Comment: Es un int, es para validar un número para saber la cantidad que hay en un inventario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya pude solucionarlo. Después de investigar en varios lugares y no encontrar respuesta la solución era aún más tonta de lo que parece pero así mismo era algo que no hubiese pensado hasta hace un momento.

El código de la solución es el siguiente:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvagregarp.Rows)
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells["cantidad"].Value).Trim() != string.Empty)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No está vacío");
                }
                cone.Close();
            }
```

De esa forma valida que la celda no esté vacía. Gracias por la respuesta igualmente!

Comment: Márcala como respuesta haciendo click en el check del costado, solo tu como creador de la pregunta puede verlo. De este modo, ayudas a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Gracias por la comprensión :D